# Removing list property for a single list item

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is, to remove a `<ul>` property from a specific `<li>`. In my case, I have a background-image in list (`<ul>`) that spreads along all list items (`<li>`). But at the last item, I don't want the background image to be applied. To give an example I'm sharing a sample code:

html:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
  <li class="item">
  <li class="item">
  <li class="itemLast">
</ul>
```

css:

```
.list{
    background-image: url(somepicture.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: auto 12px;
    background-position: 6px 0px;
}
```

This is the ul class. What I've tried so far is to remove the property in css file:

```
.itemLast{
     background-image: none;
}
```

but unfortunately this didn't work. Is there a way to get this done via css?

Comment: No there is not other than applying a separate background to that item to cover the parent bac9..

Comment: What exactly do you want the background on the rest of the list to look like? Do you mind some of it just being cut off by the last item or do you want it to show completely behind the whole list except for the last item or do you want it to do the equivalent of cover on all but the last li item...?

Comment: @AHaworth it can be cut off, after a specific item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because background is on parent, not on child. You can hide background with new background:

```css
.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item.last {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">TEXT</li>
  <li class="item">TEXT</li>
  <li class="item">TEXT</li>
  <li class="item last">TEXT</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems kind of hacking, but it worked.

Comment: @FatihErsoy Your solution would work if each of `.item` would have it's own background

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set `background: none`. Alternatively you can also target the last item from your list via

```
.list li {
  background: yellow;
}

.list li:last-child {
   background: none;
}
```

Comment: But background is on parent, child element can't cancel parent background

Comment: You are correct, I've updated my answer to target the li-elem. However, since the TS is using a background-image I feel your answer suits better to his/her needs. +1

Comment: I thought this solution should work, but it didn't. I don't know why, may be I did something wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you added the snippet, but still had your original CSS in place too.